# how to display MJPEG over the android

Tags: android

I want to display MJPEG (generated by live camera) in the Android device. is this possible to display MJPEG over the android device. if yes then how I will implement it.

Comment: Kindly [review a good example with code][1] and ask a mode detailed question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg

Answer (score 0):

WebKit supports MJPEG streams natively. You should be able to use WebView.

Comment: i try it.i think it is event not possible with the WebView. Live camera link is following :http://82.95.192.129:443/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?camera=1&resolution=352x288

Answer (score 0):

I too tried using using a WebView control to display mjpeg without success. See [Android and MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg#tab-top) for info on how to implement an mjpeg player using SurfaceView.