# Streaming video from RPI to android via UV4L. But Webview is showing white blank screen

Tags: java, android, webview, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to send a video stream from my RPI cam to my android via UV4L and show it using Webview. But the Webview keeps showing white blank screen.

The video stream works fine if i use chrome to access.

Thank you for your help!

**Mainactivity.java**

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://ip:8080/stream/video.mjpeg");

}
```

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: If you see video normally in Chrome it means the problem in Android itself. Try that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451539/viewing-mjpeg-video-streams