# How to connect with camera by IP?

Tags: android

I have got a task to make application which can to connect to camera by IP and show video from it. But I'm a new developer and I don't know it is possible or not. Please, give me an advice.

Comment: Whoever gave you the task can surely point you towards some documentation for the cameras in question?

Comment: Would if the task was given to him by someone who doesn't know?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's any help, there are TONS of "IP camera"'s around. Generally, its just a matter of some simple HTML/JS code to grab the stream, or they abide by one of the video streaming protocols.

- RTSP: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820888/java-rtsp-client-server-library)
- RTP: Use the [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) library.

I can help out a little more if you tell me the IP camera you have in mind, and the protocol you want to stream in, but as long as the camera doesn't use some strange protocol, it should be possible.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for comment. Am I able to connect with you later when I get protocol from client? Give me anything info please - skype/email. It is very important for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slew of existing Android IP camera apps:

http://market.android.com/details?id=com.pas.webcam

http://market.android.com/details?id=com.leadapps.android.mlivecams

To get you started in the field, review info from the IP camera industry organization http://www.onvif.org

[OSS Linux SW](http://www.zoneminder.com/downloads) for talking to IP cameras.

Kindly review [previous SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490707/getting-ip-cam-video-stream-on-android-mjepg) and this [great one with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg).