# MJPEG-Stream on Samsung Galaxy S2 faster than on Samsung Galaxy Tab2?

Tags: android, webcam, tablet, samsung-mobile, mjpeg

I have implement a android-app to switch between webcams. And i use this code [Android ICS and MJPEG using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask) . It works very well. But now the problem. After detailed tests on Samsung Galaxy S2 i have bought me a Samsung Galaxy Tab2. On the tablet, the Mjpeg-View works only delayed (5seconds). Is it a setting-problem (tablet)? Or has anyone an other idea? Thanks for all answers in advance. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well the Samsung Galaxy S2 has a slightly stronger processor and a smaller screen, perhaps that's why it's faster than the tab. Although 5 seconds seems like a lot... are they running the same Android version?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But I dont believe that it is the processor (S2 = 2x1,2GHz and Tab2 = 2x1GHz). Because 5sec is really o lot. Yes on both is the same Android-Version. It is really curious. If i use WebBrowser of the tablet, the video runs without delay.

Comment: Strange then, since the software is essentially the same and the hardware is not so different, it may have something to do with optimization for the Tablet... Maybe you can put some stop points in your code to find out what method exactly is taking time to execute and post it here so people can answer your question.