# streaming only RTSP MJPEG and metadata android

Tags: android, http, rtsp, mjpeg

I've been having the following problem for some days now...

I have a server which send me an url like `rtsp://ip:port/` with an active streaming session.

The format is MJPEG and I have some metadata in each frame. So I need to extract data from the stream.

I know MJPEG is not supported on Android (so no Mediaplayer), but I found a way to play it in a videoView using [Android ICS and MJPEG using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask) and httpclient. But I have only rtsp url.

Details:

- I have only rtsp url, no http.
- httprequest doesn't work with rtsp urls.

The best thing would be a way to get an Mjpeginputstream (see link above) from rtsp urls, but I don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: you cannot. RTSP is a different protocol than HTTP. See [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTSP#Protocol_directives) for a further introduction. Although some of the RTSP requests looks like HTTP requests in parameter syntax and error codes, they are different. For example, you are required to setup a playback request from a URL and afterwards you can execute a play command, as opposed to a simple GET request in HTTP

But, as you already are aware: the URL you are requesting is not an HTTP URL, but the description of the stream. The actual protocol most likely is RTP with MJPEG as codec. Inspection of the network traffic will give you that information.