# Android and MJPEG with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, stream, mjpeg, ip-camera

I have implemented the demo from the post:
[Android and MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg/3305276#3305276)

But the application always occur error after a while later and I got the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Unicode sequence: illegal character
```

within the following code in class `MjpegViewThread`:

```
public void run() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
    Bitmap bm;
    int width;
    int height;
    Rect destRect;
    Canvas c = null;
    Paint p = new Paint();
    String fps = "";
    while (mRun)
    {
        if(surfaceDone)
        {
            try
            {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                        destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
                        c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                        c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                        if(showFps) {
                            p.setXfermode(mode);
                            if(ovl != null) {
                                height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom-ovl.getHeight();
                                width  = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right -ovl.getWidth();
                                c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                            }
                            p.setXfermode(null);
                            frameCounter++;
                            if((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000) {
                                fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter)+"fps";
                                frameCounter = 0; 
                                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Error: "+e);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "Error: "+e);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (c != null)
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure whether the following LogCat information is helpful.

```
    09-27 17:06:36.645: D/dalvikvm(10120): threadid=9: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
    09-27 17:06:46.745: D/dalvikvm(10120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 132K, 47% free 2998K/5575K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 44ms
    09-27 17:06:46.825: D/dalvikvm(10120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 65K, 47% free 2997K/5639K, external 2227K/2779K, paused 27ms
    09-27 17:06:46.955: D/dalvikvm(10120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 127K, 48% free 2997K/5703K, external 2827K/2827K, paused 40ms
    09-27 17:06:47.385: D/dalvikvm(10120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 142K, 48% free 3000K/5703K, external 2827K/2827K, paused 31ms
    09-27 17:06:47.515: D/dalvikvm(10120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 131K, 48% free 2997K/5703K, external 2827K/2827K, paused 27ms
    09-27 17:06:47.615: D/dalvikvm(10120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 127K, 48% free 2997K/5703K, external 2827K/2827K, paused 31ms
```

Could anyone can give me some clues to solve this problem ?

Comment: Hello @Indiana, have you resolved this issue? I am getting the same exception...

Comment: Use   this  link  

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old but I found a solution for this problem, the code works perfectly, it is the camera, the FPS is probably set to being "variable" or "auto".  I was using a TrendNet TV-IP551WI and the default setting was "auto" for the FPS and I noticed after maybe 5 -15sec the program would crash and I would get that very error, I also noticed that it was very jerky which led me to believe the fps wasn't right.  But after setting the fps to a fixed rate (doesn't matter what just choose one, I chose 20) the error should go away and it shouldn't spaz out anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [neuralassembly's code for mjpegview](http://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplemjpegview) as a new dummy project.
It's the same code but with added enhancement.
I've had same problem then tried his code with some adjustment, and it works like a charm.

Plus, if you encountered **ndk_project_path=null** while gradle is building, add this chunk of codes below in **build.gradle** inside the **android** tag:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main'
}
```

Hope this helps other people.