# Error on resume, mjpeg view app

Tags: android, mjpeg

I checkde [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask) for show mjpeg on my android device.

I tested two links. One is sample link in example code. Other is my cam (APM-H804-WS) link.
The problem happened only on using my cam link.

First executing works well. Turn off the screen, or press home button will make example app disactive. The problem happens here.

Other screen which I see cam's stops. If nothing doing and wait, it disconnected. If I kill example app by like task killer, screen re-starts to move. Even if resume app, it works same. The only way that problem doesn't happen is quickly reload app and wish it connects well. (with log 2. Request finished, status = 200)

No problem when use sample link. Also no problem when use 'IP Camera viewer lite'.

I don`t know where I should fix it...

Comment: [log using private cam](http://minusculus.tistory.com/attachment/cfile26.uf@1360D34850CD8F9823BE0B.txt) / [log using example cam](http://minusculus.tistory.com/attachment/cfile23.uf@1869084850CD8F9C14B470.txt) Do you mean down frame?

Comment: I just close activity using code 'android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());' on Pause(). It works well. But I think there is other way with living process.

Comment: Well.. I solved. That`s simple. Clear sub-view from layout and add. Without remove sub-view, black screen appears. Any else is on that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask).

Comment: I found other bug with thread. when thread which has same name already running, error occurs. To avoid it, there may be a lot of ways. I used sharing string as saving thread name. if newly made thread name equals saved, don`t start. I think there is more good and simple way to solve. I wrote it because I have no place to write it ;(