# MjpegInputStream issue

Tags: java, android, streaming, mjpeg

I'm trying to view an IP camera with Android, and follow some topics I founded here, but it doesn't work in `"return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());"` on `"DoRead"` method.

I followed "[Android ICS and MJPEG using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask)"

This is the error log:

> 08-13 09:28:11.260: D/CLIPBOARD(4135): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
>   08-13 09:28:30.310: D/MJPEG(4577): 1. Sending http request
>   08-13 09:28:30.450: D/CLIPBOARD(4577): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
>   08-13 09:28:31.010: D/MJPEG(4577): 2. Request finished, status = 200
>   08-13 09:28:31.010: D/MJPEG(4577): 3. Traza
>   08-13 09:28:31.010: W/dalvikvm(4577): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/camera/simplemjpeg/MjpegInputStream;
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: W/dalvikvm(4577): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5e1f8)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at com.camera.simplemjpeg.MjpegActivity$DoRead.doInBackground(MjpegActivity.java:205)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at com.camera.simplemjpeg.MjpegActivity$DoRead.doInBackground(MjpegActivity.java:1)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     ... 4 more
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ImageProc: findLibrary returned null
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     at com.camera.simplemjpeg.MjpegInputStream.(MjpegInputStream.java:48)
>   08-13 09:28:31.020: E/AndroidRuntime(4577):     ... 8 more
>   08-13 09:28:36.070: W/SurfaceView(4577): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false