# How to set delay time for the AsyncTask execution when it uses also another Thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I would like to set delay time in milliseconds for the class which extends AsyncTask. But this class is using also another java Thread. There are classes to stream Mjpeg on Android with some few changes from this question: [Android ICS and MJPEG using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask)

This is my class which Extends AsyncTask:

```
public class GetCameraMjpeg extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MjpegInputStream> {

    @Override
    protected MjpegInputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            if (username != null && password != null) {
                String authEncoded = Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authEncoded);
            }
            connection.connect();
            return new MjpegInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(MjpegInputStream result) {
        mjpegView.setSource(result);
        mjpegView.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

`MjpegInputStream` class is the same as in the Stackoverflow question pasted above. And the `MjpegView` is the class extending SurfaceView. It contains inner class `MjpegViewThread` which is the class extending java `Thread` class. And this is the `run` method of this thread.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Rect destRect;
    Canvas canvas = null;
    while (mjpegRun) {
        if (surfaceDone) {
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) {
                    synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                        try {
                            bitmap = mjpegInputStream.readMjpegFrame();
                            if (displayMode != SIZE_FULLSCREEN) {
                                displayWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
                                displayHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                            }
                            destRect = destRect(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, destRect, new Paint());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.getStackTrace();
                            Log.d(TAG, "catch IOException hit in run", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with this answer: [How to execute Async task repeatedly after fixed time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531950/how-to-execute-async-task-repeatedly-after-fixed-time-intervals) but there is not noticeable difference. I suppose it is that `MjpegView` runs its own java `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

use the handler
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelay(function, time);