# MjpegView with other XML layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, video-streaming, mjpeg

I'm developing an APP that needs to gets the stream of an Airdrone through mjpeg.

I'm using the classes from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask). It works great with the example but I need to add some other elements to the same view such as the buttons to control de airdrome.

The example code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    mv = new MjpegView(this);
    setContentView(mv);
    ...
```

What i'm trying to do but is not working...

```
...
mv = (MjpegView) findViewById(R.id.mv);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
...
```

And my layout xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.gabilheri.rosbridgecontroller.app.TestActivity"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
    <com.gabilheri.rosbridgecontroller.app.VideoStreamClasses.MjpegView
        android:id="@+id/mv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

This is the LOGCAT error:

```
04-26 22:40:19.521    2229-2229/com.gabilheri.rosbridgecontroller.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gabilheri.rosbridgecontroller.app, PID: 2229
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.gabilheri.rosbridgecontroller.app.TestActivity$DoRead.onPostExecute(TestActivity.java:86)
        at com.gabilheri.rosbridgecontroller.app.TestActivity$DoRead.onPostExecute(TestActivity.java:59)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5184)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This are the lines from the method onPost execute:

```
mv.setSource(result);  //Line 86
mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT); // Line 87
mv.showFps(true); // Line 88
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you! :D

Comment: Which is this line : `TestActivity.java:86`

Comment: Edited the original post to add those lines.

Comment: Seems like `MjpegInputStream result` param to `onPostExecute` is `Null` .

Comment: I can see that. What I'm trying to  understand is why it happens in the second case but not in the first one :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out what was my problem...

I was trying to do:

```
mv = (MjpegView) findViewById(R.id.mv);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
```

And was getting a NullPointerException.. I changed to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
mv = (MjpegView) findViewById(R.id.mv);
```

And now everything is working like is supposed to be :)

Comment: marcus am also trying to implement the same using xml ,i do as per your answer but the streaming image is not happening but if i use programatically it workz why?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Is the app crashing or simple getting a black screen?

Comment: simple getting a black screen

Comment: How are you setting up the video source? Are you using the example with the Async Task found [in this tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask) ? 

If so.. try adding moving the:
`new DoRead().execute(cameraUrl);`
to the onResume method.