# Android MJPEG stream

Tags: android, video-streaming, mjpeg

I have implemented [Android and MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg/3305276#3305276)

and also implemented async and certifications to run it that is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask). Now i have managed to run the jpeg video stream but the issue is It keeps blinking when running the stream. It keeps getting on and off. I think it could be the issue of frames. Anyone has the idea how to handle this. Here is the complete code that i have implemented:

MjpegSample.java

```
public class MjpegSample extends Activity {

private static final boolean DEBUG=true;
private static final String TAG = "MJPEG";
private MjpegView mv;
private static final int MENU_QUIT = 1;
String URL;
MjpegInputStream inputStream;
/* Creates the menu items */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
menu.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, "Quit");
return true;
}

/* Handles item selections */
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_QUIT:
            finish();
            return true;    
        }    
    return false;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    //sample public cam
    URL = "https://orangefr-eu-oem-storage11.mios.com/storage/storage/store/81976/archive?Key=2147780009";
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    mv = new MjpegView(this);
    setContentView(mv);        
    new DoRead().execute(URL);
}

public class DoRead extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MjpegInputStream> {
    protected MjpegInputStream doInBackground(String... url) {
        //TODO: if camera has authentication deal with it and don't just not work
        HttpResponse res = null;         
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        HttpParams httpParams = httpclient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5*1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5*1000);
        if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "1. Sending http request");
        try {
            res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url[0])));
            if(DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "2. Request finished, status = " + res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            if(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==401){
                //You must turn off camera User Access Control before this will work
                return null;
            }
            return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());  
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            if(DEBUG){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Request failed-ClientProtocolException", e);
            }
            //Error connecting to camera
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(DEBUG){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Request failed-IOException", e);
            }
            //Error connecting to camera
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(MjpegInputStream result) {
        mv.setSource(result);
        /*if(result!=null){
            result.setSkip(1);
            setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }else{
            setTitle(R.string.title_disconnected);
        }*/
        mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN);
        mv.showFps(false);
    }
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mv.stopPlayback();
}
```

}

MjpegView.java

```
public class MjpegView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
public final static int POSITION_UPPER_LEFT  = 9;
public final static int POSITION_UPPER_RIGHT = 3;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_LEFT  = 12;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT = 6;

public final static int SIZE_STANDARD   = 1; 
public final static int SIZE_BEST_FIT   = 4;
public final static int SIZE_FULLSCREEN = 8;

private MjpegViewThread thread;
private MjpegInputStream mIn = null;    
private boolean showFps = false;
private boolean mRun = false;
private boolean surfaceDone = false;    
private Paint overlayPaint;
private int overlayTextColor;
private int overlayBackgroundColor;
private int ovlPos;
private int dispWidth;
private int dispHeight;
private int displayMode;

public class MjpegViewThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private int frameCounter = 0;
    private long start;
    private Bitmap ovl;

    public MjpegViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) { mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder; }

    private Rect destRect(int bmw, int bmh) {
        int tempx;
        int tempy;
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD) {
            tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
            tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
            return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
        }
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT) {
            float bmasp = (float) bmw / (float) bmh;
            bmw = dispWidth;
            bmh = (int) (dispWidth / bmasp);
            if (bmh > dispHeight) {
                bmh = dispHeight;
                bmw = (int) (dispHeight * bmasp);
            }
            tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
            tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
            return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
        }
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN) return new Rect(0, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
        return null;
    }

    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
        synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) {
            dispWidth = width;
            dispHeight = height;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap makeFpsOverlay(Paint p, String text) {
        Rect b = new Rect();
        p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), b);
        int bwidth  = b.width()+2;
        int bheight = b.height()+2;
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bwidth, bheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
        p.setColor(overlayBackgroundColor);
        c.drawRect(0, 0, bwidth, bheight, p);
        p.setColor(overlayTextColor);
        c.drawText(text, -b.left+1, (bheight/2)-((p.ascent()+p.descent())/2)+1, p);
        return bm;           
    }

    public void run() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
        Bitmap bm;
        int width;
        int height;
        Rect destRect;
        Canvas c = null;
        Paint p = new Paint();
        String fps = "";
        while (mRun) {
            if(surfaceDone) {
                try {
                    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                        try {
                            bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                            destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
                            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                            c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                            if(showFps) {
                                p.setXfermode(mode);
                                if(ovl != null) {
                                    height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom-ovl.getHeight();
                                    width  = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right -ovl.getWidth();
                                    c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                }
                                p.setXfermode(null);
                                frameCounter++;
                                if((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000) {
                                    fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter)+"fps";
                                    frameCounter = 0; 
                                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {}
                    }
                } finally { if (c != null) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void init(Context context) {
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    thread = new MjpegViewThread(holder, context);
    setFocusable(true);
    overlayPaint = new Paint();
    overlayPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    overlayPaint.setTextSize(12);
    overlayPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    overlayTextColor = Color.WHITE;
    overlayBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
    ovlPos = MjpegView.POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT;
    displayMode = MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD;
    dispWidth = getWidth();
    dispHeight = getHeight();
}

public void startPlayback() { 
    if(mIn != null) {
        mRun = true;
        thread.start();         
    }
}

public void stopPlayback() { 
    mRun = false;
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public MjpegView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); init(context); }
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h) { thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h); }

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    surfaceDone = false; 
    stopPlayback(); 
}

public MjpegView(Context context) { 
    super(context); 
    init(context); 
    }    
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    surfaceDone = true; 
    }
public void showFps(boolean b) { 
    showFps = b; 
    }
public void setSource(MjpegInputStream source) { 
    mIn = source; 
    startPlayback();
    }
public void setOverlayPaint(Paint p) { 
    overlayPaint = p; 
    }
public void setOverlayTextColor(int c) { 
    overlayTextColor = c; 
    }
public void setOverlayBackgroundColor(int c) { 
    overlayBackgroundColor = c; 
    }
public void setOverlayPosition(int p) { 
    ovlPos = p; 
    }
public void setDisplayMode(int s) { 
    displayMode = s; 
    }
```

}

MjpegInputStream.java

```
public class MjpegInputStream extends DataInputStream {
private final byte[] SOI_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD8 };
private final byte[] EOF_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD9 };
private final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
private final static int HEADER_MAX_LENGTH = 100;
private final static int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 40000 + HEADER_MAX_LENGTH;
private int mContentLength = -1;

public static MjpegInputStream read(String url) {
    HttpResponse res;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();     
    try {
        res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url)));
        return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());              
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return null;
}

public MjpegInputStream(InputStream in) { super(new BufferedInputStream(in, FRAME_MAX_LENGTH)); }

private int getEndOfSeqeunce(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int seqIndex = 0;
    byte c;
    for(int i=0; i < FRAME_MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        c = (byte) in.readUnsignedByte();
        if(c == sequence[seqIndex]) {
            seqIndex++;
            if(seqIndex == sequence.length) return i + 1;
        } else seqIndex = 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

private int getStartOfSequence(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int end = getEndOfSeqeunce(in, sequence);
    return (end < 0) ? (-1) : (end - sequence.length);
}

private int parseContentLength(byte[] headerBytes) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
    ByteArrayInputStream headerIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(headerBytes);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(headerIn);
    return Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH));
}   

public Bitmap readMjpegFrame() throws IOException {
    mark(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH);
    int headerLen = getStartOfSequence(this, SOI_MARKER);
    reset();
    byte[] header = new byte[headerLen];
    readFully(header);
    try {
        mContentLength = parseContentLength(header);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
        mContentLength = getEndOfSeqeunce(this, EOF_MARKER); 
    }
    reset();
    byte[] frameData = new byte[mContentLength];
    skipBytes(headerLen);
    readFully(frameData);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameData));
}}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have implemented a library to play MJPEG video streaming on Android. All source code is available on GitHub [ipcam-view](https://github.com/niqdev/ipcam-view).

Add the dependency to your app

```
compile 'com.github.niqdev:mjpeg-view:0.3.3'
```

Here an example of how use it, add MjpegSurfaceView to your layout

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  // ADD THIS
  xmlns:stream="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  ...>

  <com.github.niqdev.mjpeg.MjpegSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/VIEW_NAME"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    stream:type="stream_default OR stream_native" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and read the stream in your activity/fragment

```
Mjpeg.newInstance()
 .credential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
 .open("IPCAM_URL.mjpg")
 .subscribe(inputStream -> {
    mjpegView.setSource(inputStream);
    mjpegView.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.BEST_FIT);
    mjpegView.showFps(true);
 });
```

Comment: How can we convert the lambda expression to android supported code?

Comment: To make this work using the lamda expressions you will need to add plugin `apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'` to gradle. Note: jackOptions will not work with this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL, I think problem with the URL. If you want to check the streaming ,you can check with your browser or VLC player which has to stream the link. I had used the same code which is perfectly streaming from the camera which is connected to the Robot