# Why does Android draw View inside another (with width and height defined in pixels) in incorrect way?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I am wondering in which way Android draws views on the screen inside layout views with defined `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` values in pixels.

I am using Android class view extends `android.view.SurfaceView`. It is just `MjpegView` to display MJPEG stream from the camera on the Android app. I am working with this code (with some small changes): [Android ICS and MJPEG using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask)

This `MjpegView` class is placed inside the `RelativeLayout`. `MjpegView` object is added programmatically and this `RelativeLayout` has attributes defined in this way:

```
android:layout_width="800px"
android:layout_height="600px"
```

This size values is necessary for this application so I can't change them. Application is working only in landscape orientation. My `MjpegView` need to be set `320 x 240` pixels size inside  `RelativeLayout (800 x 600 px)`. My application enlarges this `RealtiveLayout` to fill the screen on the current device. And this is a problem connected also with the streaming MJPEG. I am working on Nexus 7 (2012 version), which has `1280 x 800` resolution.

To get the real size of this view inside layout I have to measured the height of the Nexus 7 screen without action and navigation bars. To get this I have used this method inside one `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
    if (parentLayout != null && isLandscape) {
        this.measuredActivityHeight = parentLayout.getBottom();
    }
}
```

I am getting `703` value as the `measuredActivityHeight` of the running Activity. So to get the ratio in which Android translates `320 x 240 px` inside `800 x 600 px` to the `dp` value on the screen I have written this method:

```
 public int calculateForCurrentScreen(float pixelValue) {
    float ratio = PageActivity.measuredActivityHeight / 600f;
    int result = (int) (pixelValue * ratio);
    return result;
}
```

So for the `320 x 240 px` on the Nexus 7 I am getting `374 x 281`. And to get `MjpegView` in this size I need to use this method inside the `MjpegView` class:

```
public void setResolution(int width, int height) {
    holder.setFixedSize(width, height);
}
```

And the size of the streaming view is in the wanted size. But this view has additional black areas. So in fact the whole view (camera stream + black areas on the its bottom and right side) has `440 x 328` size.

I have checked that `Rect` object in `MjpegView` is drawing with `374 x 281` size so it is OK. `SurfaceHolder` and `Canvas` also have this size. `Bitmap` object has `320 x 240` size, but this is OK because `Bitmap` object is from camera stream. And it is resized to the wanted size.

Problem disappear (there is no black areas and `MjpegView` is in correct position and size relative to other views) when I have switched `RelativeLayout` to the `800dp x 600dp` size and invoke `setResolution(320, 240)` for the `MjpegView` object. But the whole layout is in this moment too big.

**EDIT**

Thanks @mathiash for your comment. I have just uploaded screenshot from Nexus 7 (2012 edition) to show you my problem.

As you can see, the green area is the `RelativeLayout` with defined `800 x 600 px` size. To get MJPEG stream from the `http://trackfield.webcam.oregonstate.edu/`. I have used this URL: `http://trackfield.webcam.oregonstate.edu/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=320x240`.

For this screenshot I have invoked `setResolution(320, 240)` method. And black area has `374 x 281` and video stream `320 x 240`.

[image: 320x240]

For this screenshot I have invoked `setResolution(374, 281)` method. And black area is much bigger and video stream is `374 x 281`. And in this case video stream has correct size but this black area is unnecessary.

[image: 374x281]

Comment: sorry i missed your question

Comment: This question is interesting, but, I'm sorry to say, rather hard to understand. :/ Perhaps a screenshot would be useful?

Comment: @matiash thanks for your comment, I have updated my question with the sreenshots

Comment: Well, one thing Android teaches you is to never use concrete pixel values. Use ratios and dp.

Comment: @LeventeKurusa Well I have tried with `800 x 600 dp`. And it looks OK, but my app supports zooming in with two fingers gesture, and zooming in causes that this black area is also appearing...

Answer (score 2):

As Levente Kurusa suggested, using a virtual pixel unit such as dp may solve your problem. We should avoid using px diretly.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the comment to mu question: I have tried with `800 x 600 dp` size also. And it looks OK (without black area), but my app supports zooming in with two fingers gesture, and zooming in causes that this black area is also appearing... – so using dp or pixel is not a solution. I am looking for a solution how to complex set the size of the view extending `SurfaceView`

Answer (score 1):

dont use dp, even dp changes with different screens. Instead i learned to use my own value times density. 
So use DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); and
metrics.getDensity() * 50 for example. Also try to use weights to keep them relative in different screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
whateveryourvideoname.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT)
```

in order to make the best fitting of your `inputstream` (with the resolution you set up previously) within the layout view.

---

But all this doesn't make sense if you have defined your `Mjpegview` in the `layout.xml` file with the same size as the resolution of your source image, so the best way is to skip the `setResolution` command and just use

```
whateveryourvideoname.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN)
```

and your image will fit perfectly inside your MjpegView display.