# Live video streaming from an Wireless IP Camera to Android mobile

Tags: android, rtsp, live-streaming, ip-camera

Here, I have to get live video streaming from an wireless Ip camera to android mobile using RTSP protocol.Camera is connected to the wireless router and mobile also has same wifi network.Now I need to implement live video streaming from camera.

For this purpose ,What should I do?. this is new concept for me.How to connect android mobile and camera programmatically and get live streaming.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Follow the instructions in this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/) to get it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the image live feed from your Ip Cam to your PC, mine was

`String URL = "http://192.168.1.8/image/jpeg.cgi";`

or some sort. You should check your device if that is included. You can then download the image and put it on the imageview. not the actual image file just its graphical details. You can search for MJpegInputStream for that, heres the sample code for it

```
public class MjpegInputStream extends DataInputStream {
private final byte[] SOI_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD8 };
private final byte[] EOF_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD9 };
private final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
private final static int HEADER_MAX_LENGTH = 100;
private final static int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 40000 + HEADER_MAX_LENGTH;
private int mContentLength = -1;

public static MjpegInputStream read(Context context,String url) {
    HttpResponse res;
    MyHttpClient httpclient = new MyHttpClient( context );     
    try {
        res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url)));
        return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());              
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return null;
}

public MjpegInputStream(InputStream in) { super(new BufferedInputStream(in, FRAME_MAX_LENGTH)); }

private int getEndOfSeqeunce(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int seqIndex = 0;
    byte c;
    for(int i=0; i < FRAME_MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        c = (byte) in.readUnsignedByte();
        if(c == sequence[seqIndex]) {
            seqIndex++;
            if(seqIndex == sequence.length) return i + 1;
        } else seqIndex = 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

private int getStartOfSequence(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int end = getEndOfSeqeunce(in, sequence);
    return (end < 0) ? (-1) : (end - sequence.length);
}

private int parseContentLength(byte[] headerBytes) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
    ByteArrayInputStream headerIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(headerBytes);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(headerIn);
    return Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH));
}   

public Bitmap readMjpegFrame() throws IOException {
    mark(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH);
    int headerLen = getStartOfSequence(this, SOI_MARKER);
    reset();
    byte[] header = new byte[headerLen];
    readFully(header);
    try {
        mContentLength = parseContentLength(header);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
        mContentLength = getEndOfSeqeunce(this, EOF_MARKER); 
    }
    reset();
    byte[] frameData = new byte[mContentLength];
    skipBytes(headerLen);
    readFully(frameData);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameData));
}
```

You can look more about MJpegInput stream [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10550139/android-ics-and-mjpeg-using-asynctask) and [here](https://github.com/moustaki/raspbaby/blob/master/raspbaby-android/src/org/moustaki/raspbaby/MjpegInputStream.java)

hope its helpful, happy codings.