# ignore ssl errors in DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, ssl

Im searching for a possibility to ignore all ssl errors (eg. not trusted) in a default httpclient. I've seen lots of solutions here, but i alwas have to import a specific certificate an add it to the trustmanager or it is for HttpsUrlConnection instad of DefaultHttpClient.
My used webrequests are:

```
    public static String makeGETRequest(String s,String encoding)
{
    DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final String username = "USERNAME";
    final String password = "PASSWORD";
    UsernamePasswordCredentials c = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,password);
    BasicCredentialsProvider cP = new BasicCredentialsProvider(); 
    cP.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, c); 
    http.setCredentialsProvider(cP);
    HttpResponse res;
    try {

        res = http.execute(new HttpGet(s));
        InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
              baf.append((byte)current);
         }

        return  new String(baf.toByteArray(),encoding);
       } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return "error: " + e.getMessage();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return "error: " + e.getMessage();
    } 

}
```

And:

```
public static String makePOSTRequest(String s, List <NameValuePair> nvps,String encoding)
{
    DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final String username = "USERNAME";
    final String password = "PASSWORD";
    UsernamePasswordCredentials c = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,password);
    BasicCredentialsProvider cP = new BasicCredentialsProvider(); 
    cP.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, c); 
    http.setCredentialsProvider(cP);
    HttpResponse res;
    try {
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(s);
        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET));
        res = http.execute(httpost);
        InputStream is = res.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
              baf.append((byte)current);
         }
        res = null;
        httpost = null;
        String ret = new String(baf.toByteArray(),encoding);
        return  ret;
       } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return e.getMessage();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return e.getMessage();
    } 

}
```

Did anyone know how to ignore ssl errors in this code?

edit:
because I have to trust only one specific (expired) certificate, I try to overwrite the  DefaultHttpClient in the following way:

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
final Context context;

  public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }

  private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
      KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
      InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mykeystore);
      try {
        trusted.load(in, "mypassword".toCharArray());
      } finally {
        in.close();
      }
      return new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }
```

}

The file in R.raw.mykeystore is a .bks file, which I created with  [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/), I make a new bks and imported the stored pem of the expired certificate, it seemes to work and the keystored is loaded without errors, but if I perform the request, i get a IO Exception with the message "no peer certificate", what might be the problem?

Comment: 'Ignoring SSL errors (e.g. not trusted)' is insecure. See RFC 2246. If you don't want it secure why use SSL at all?

Comment: thanks for transforming into comment ;) as i wrote, the expired ssl certificate is from a third party proxy, i told them to install a valid one, but i have to wirite a quick workaround to enable the functions for my customers, while the certificate is expired...

Comment: Following EJP's comment, tolerating expired certificates selectively and letting absolutely any certificate through are very different things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the problem. It works if you use the above request, but instead of the DefaultHttpClient, use your own version:

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
final Context context;
TrustManager easyTrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }    
};
  public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }


  private MySSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
      KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");      
      try {
         trusted.load(null, null);

      } finally {
      }

      MySSLSocketFactory sslfactory =  new MySSLSocketFactory(trusted);
        sslfactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        return sslfactory;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }

  }
  public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super(truststore);

            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: this code will peoduce an broken pipe error in os version 2.2, fixed in 2.3.3 +

Comment: Unused field easyTrustManager!