# DefaultHttpClient() with expired SSL

Tags: android, http, ssl

Tried almost everything and got no success making DefaultHttpClient() to work with expired SSL certificate. Does anybody have some example or something that can help. Android SDK 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `TrustManager` to handle expired SSL certificates.
This post in SO [ignore ssl errors in default httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229929/ignore-ssl-errors-in-defaulthttpclient) has some code to look at, but essentially it accepts all certificates.

Not sure why would you want to accept expired certificates but I would recommend to **not** do it.

Comment: Code given in your URL does not work with android 2.2. Tried with 2.3 and later - everything is fine. Is there any way to fix it ?