# creating Video from Android screen activities

Tags: android

In my app I have a requirement to create a video from the screen activities programatically.  (ie: I am running some animations for some time I need to convert these animations to a video, like video demos.)

I have been searching for this for the last week, but I haven't found any solution.  I don't know whether it is possible in Android or not. If it is, please tell me the way or suggest me some links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to capture the screenshots from "within your activity", it is possible. Follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353279/android-taking-a-screen-shot)

Having grabbed the screenshoton a bitmap, you need to encode the frames to a video yourself.

Captured bitmap --> JNI (Native-bitmap) --> feed input buffer to a native encoder (ffmpeg) --> save to file

Comment: Hi peasea thanks for your valuable answer. now i took the screen shots and saving to the sd card. i dont know how to encode the frames ta a video. If possible can you provide the links or code

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632607/how-to-save-the-mjpeg-stream-as-3gp-or-mp4-format-video-files-to-the-sdcard-in-a) a similar thread running. You guys may collaborate :)

Answer (score -2):

This project will meet your request [Android-MJPEG-Video-Capture-FFMPEG](https://github.com/vanevery/Android-MJPEG-Video-Capture-FFMPEG.git)
It is just to convert jpegs into a movie file by ffmpeg bin