# Saving .cgi stream image format as Video

Tags: android, video, bitmap, cgi

I am creating a video streaming app which uses a IP Camera as external device.
I can already get the image (.cgi format) from the ip url of the device(192.168.x.x/image/image.cgi). I can update the image view every several milli seconds to update its content and its working great, no issues there.

The question is, can I save this bitmaps as video (.mp4)? I tried MediaRecorder before and works, is there a way to do that on streaming bitmaps ?

thanks

Comment: cgi is not an image format. It the the name of the program that is generating the image (image.cgi). It stands for Common Gateway Interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "video" is a stream of jpeg images.

See
http://thistleshrub.net/Joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=115:displaying-streamed-mjpeg-in-java&catid=43:robotics&Itemid=64

for some java code that displays such images. You need to transcode the images to a different format. E.g. on the command line that can be done with

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12193/transcoding-mjpeg-stream-to-flv-or-mp4

Doing this on android has been discussed at [how to save the mjpeg stream as 3gp or mp4 format video files to the sdcard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632607/how-to-save-the-mjpeg-stream-as-3gp-or-mp4-format-video-files-to-the-sdcard-in-a)

googling for mjpegstream video convert gives you more results ...

Comment: I'm switching up my site and not dealing with URL rewrites.  New URL for the MJPEG sample http://thistleshrub.net/www/index.php?controller=posts&action=show&id=2012-05-13DisplayingStreamedMJPEGinJava.txt