# For Android, how to play live streaming from url for a camera that broadcasting live

Tags: android, url, video, live-streaming

I am trying to play a live stream video from URLs (mjpeg, ws, and flash) but these links are not working on Android neither by VideoView nor MediaController, although I open the web browser on my pc and I copied the links and they worked fine.

Here are the links:

```
    "ws": "ws://176.34.175.163:8000/camera/s7RIqmHU/?t=180&ts=1346851352&digest=5IaMR3hKO67azIE1zt1AIogYxpM.",
    "mjpeg": "http://176.34.175.163:8000/camera/s7RIqmHU/?t=180&ts=1346851352&digest=5IaMR3hKO67azIE1zt1AIogYxpM.",
    "flash": "http://176.34.175.163:8000/camera/s7RIqmHU/?t=180&ts=1346851352&digest=5IaMR3hKO67azIE1zt1AIogYxpM."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the formats you've specified are natively supported by the VideoView or MediaController classes. For MJPEG, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg). Flash/ws are just generally complex enough that you're probably not going to find a trivial, off-the-shelf solution.