# Android, mjpeg, http certificates

Tags: android, certificate, raspberry-pi, mjpeg

I just start to learn android programming and I'm not that experienced in java either.
I am trying to make an application in android that stream a mjpeg from raspberry pi (using mjpeg-streamer). The address pattern is:

```
http://ip_address:8080/?action=stream
```

The raspberry pi part is finished. The problem is in the Android part.. I tried the code from this one:
[Android and MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg)

and then i got a black screen and it crash.. from the comments on that page, i found that i need to get the http certificates or such..

I tried several solutions to trust all certificates but i got some syntax errors. For example, from this page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12742591

i got an error on the line where it says (appx line 83):

```
super(null, null, null, null, null, (X509HostnameVerifier)null);
```

The error is:

```
The constructor SSLSocketFactory(null, null, null, null, null, X509HostnameVerifier) is undefined
```

And I don't know how to fix it since i'm new on this topic.. Eclipse suggest to change (X509HostnameVerifier) to (HostNameResolver). But then I got confused on where to edit in the mjpeg part.

I think I should change (appx line 29):

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

to

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = HttpsClientBuilder.getBelieverHttpsClient();
```

It still crash.
I didn't change any of the code from the pages above except that 2 lines mentioned.
Any suggestion?

I just want to trust all certificates, since when the raspberry pi restart, sometime it change the ip address. If the ip address change, I have to get a new certificates right?

**Edit**

I forgot to add uses permission for internet.. this is the new logcat:

```
01-21 18:02:48.825: W/dalvikvm(27150): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c4d1f8)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1973)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1999)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4513)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:974)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:741)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:138)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at com.example.testviewer.MjpegInputStream.read(MjpegInputStream.java:31)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at com.example.testviewer.MjpegSample.onCreate(MjpegSample.java:40)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
01-21 18:02:48.830: E/AndroidRuntime(27150):    ... 11 more
01-21 18:02:57.795: I/Process(27150): Sending signal. PID: 27150 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Hi, can you please post the exception log from logcat please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any idea about the http certificates but your log shows that your application is crashing because of `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` . This means you are running your network operations on the application main thread which is reserved for handling UI interactions.

Move your network call to another thread or use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class to run the network calls in the background to get past this exception.