# Live mjpeg video stream from server to android

Tags: android, video-streaming, mjpeg

I am trying to fetch mjpeg live video stream from server to android.I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg#tab-top) answer.it is very helpful to me.It works with [this](http://trackfield.webcam.oregonstate.edu/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=800x600&dummy=1333689998337) demo url.But, In my video stream it asking for username and password.

To set url into MjpegView:

```
 setContentView(mv);        
 mv.setSource(MjpegInputStream.read(URL));
```

MjpegInputStream:

```
public static MjpegInputStream read(String url) {
    HttpResponse res;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();     

   
    try {
        res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url)));
        return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());              
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

As in web browser whenever i open my server link..it asking for 'password' & 'username'.so
where to put params in this read() ? and also want to know if my live video is in  **H.264**
format. then how can i convert it into **MJPEG**  format?Also its speed is very slow and not smooth.how to improve it?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You are promted for a login because the webcam is password protected. Normally with webcams you have to pass the username and password as part of the URL. eg. username:password@ip.address.or.dyndns.com:8085/folder/stream.jpg?size=large where the number at the end is the port number.

Answer (score 0):

it's been a time... but to login:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {

        HttpGet httpget2 = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget2.addHeader("Authorization","Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((USERSTRING:PASSWORDSTRING).getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));
        res = httpclient.execute(httpget2);
        return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```