# Placing custom views in Layout in Android

Tags: android, object, layout, view, function-calls

I'm developing different classes and defining objects from these classes 
and for each object there are some functions that I'm calling when a button is pressed or the screen is touched

I want to place my objects as in the picture in [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

When I place these objects using the following way, I can not call the functions of each class

this is the code I'm using I took it from [Android and MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg/3305276#3305276)

This the **main activity**

```
package de.mjpegsample;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import de.mjpegsample.MjpegView.MjpegInputStream;
import de.mjpegsample.MjpegView.MjpegView;

public class MjpegSample extends Activity {

private MjpegView mv;
private MjpegView mv2;

private static final int MENU_QUIT = 1;


public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //sample public cam
    String URL = "http://gamic.dnsalias.net:7001/img/video.mjpeg";
    mv = (MjpegView)findViewById(R.id.mjpegView1);
    mv2 = (MjpegView)findViewById(R.id.mjpegView2);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    mv.init(this);
    mv2.init(this);

   }

 public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mv.stopPlayback();
 }
 }
```

**MjpegView Class**

```
package de.mjpegsample.MjpegView;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MjpegView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
public final static int POSITION_UPPER_LEFT  = 9;
public final static int POSITION_UPPER_RIGHT = 3;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_LEFT  = 12;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT = 6;

public final static int SIZE_STANDARD   = 1; 
public final static int SIZE_BEST_FIT   = 4;
public final static int SIZE_FULLSCREEN = 8;

private MjpegViewThread thread;
private MjpegInputStream mIn = null;    
private boolean showFps = false;
private boolean mRun = false;
private boolean surfaceDone = false;    
private Paint overlayPaint;
private int overlayTextColor;
private int overlayBackgroundColor;
private int ovlPos;
private int dispWidth;
private int dispHeight;
private int displayMode;

public class MjpegViewThread extends Thread {
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private int frameCounter = 0;
private long start;
private Bitmap ovl;

    public MjpegViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) { mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder; }

    private Rect destRect(int bmw, int bmh) {
        int tempx;
        int tempy;
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD) {
            tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
            tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
            return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
        }
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT) {
            float bmasp = (float) bmw / (float) bmh;
            bmw = dispWidth;
            bmh = (int) (dispWidth / bmasp);
            if (bmh > dispHeight) {
                bmh = dispHeight;
                bmw = (int) (dispHeight * bmasp);
            }
            tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
            tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
            return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
        }
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN) return new Rect(0, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
        return null;
    }

    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
        synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) {
            dispWidth = width;
            dispHeight = height;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap makeFpsOverlay(Paint p, String text) {
        Rect b = new Rect();
        p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), b);
        int bwidth  = b.width()+2;
        int bheight = b.height()+2;
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bwidth, bheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
        p.setColor(overlayBackgroundColor);
        c.drawRect(0, 0, bwidth, bheight, p);
        p.setColor(overlayTextColor);
        c.drawText(text, -b.left+1, (bheight/2)-((p.ascent()+p.descent())/2)+1, p);
        return bm;           
    }

    public void run() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
        Bitmap bm;
        int width;
        int height;
        Rect destRect;
        Canvas c = null;
        Paint p = new Paint();
        String fps = "";
        while (mRun) {
            if(surfaceDone) {
                try {
                    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                        try {
                            bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                            destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
                            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                            c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                            if(showFps) {
                                p.setXfermode(mode);
                                if(ovl != null) {
                                    height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom-ovl.getHeight();
                                    width  = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right -ovl.getWidth();
                                    c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                }
                                p.setXfermode(null);
                                frameCounter++;
                                if((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000) {
                                    fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter)+"fps";
                                    frameCounter = 0; 
                                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {}
                    }
                } finally { if (c != null) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void init(Context context) {
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    thread = new MjpegViewThread(holder, context);
    setFocusable(true);
    overlayPaint = new Paint();
    overlayPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    overlayPaint.setTextSize(12);
    overlayPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    overlayTextColor = Color.WHITE;
    overlayBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
    ovlPos = MjpegView.POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT;
    displayMode = MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD;
    dispWidth = getWidth();
    dispHeight = getHeight();
}

public void startPlayback() { 
    if(mIn != null) {
        mRun = true;
        thread.start();         
    }
}

public void stopPlayback() { 
    mRun = false;
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public MjpegView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); init(context); }
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h) { thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h); }

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    surfaceDone = false; 
    stopPlayback(); 
}

public MjpegView(Context context) { 
    super(context); 
    init(context); 
    }    
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    surfaceDone = true; 
    }
public void showFps(boolean b) { 
    showFps = b; 
    }
public void setSource(MjpegInputStream source) { 
    mIn = source; 
    startPlayback();
    }
public void setOverlayPaint(Paint p) { 
    overlayPaint = p; 
    }
public void setOverlayTextColor(int c) { 
    overlayTextColor = c; 
    }
public void setOverlayBackgroundColor(int c) { 
    overlayBackgroundColor = c; 
    }
public void setOverlayPosition(int p) { 
    ovlPos = p; 
    }
public void setDisplayMode(int s) { 
    displayMode = s; 
    }
    }
```

**MjpegInputStream Class**

```
package de.mjpegsample.MjpegView;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class MjpegInputStream extends DataInputStream {
private final byte[] SOI_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD8 };
private final byte[] EOF_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD9 };
private final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
private final static int HEADER_MAX_LENGTH = 100;
private final static int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 40000 + HEADER_MAX_LENGTH;
private int mContentLength = -1;

public static MjpegInputStream read(String url) {
    HttpResponse res;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();     
    try {
        res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url)));
        return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());              
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return null;
}

public MjpegInputStream(InputStream in) { super(new BufferedInputStream(in, FRAME_MAX_LENGTH)); }

private int getEndOfSeqeunce(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int seqIndex = 0;
    byte c;
    for(int i=0; i < FRAME_MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        c = (byte) in.readUnsignedByte();
        if(c == sequence[seqIndex]) {
            seqIndex++;
            if(seqIndex == sequence.length) return i + 1;
        } else seqIndex = 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

private int getStartOfSequence(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int end = getEndOfSeqeunce(in, sequence);
    return (end < 0) ? (-1) : (end - sequence.length);
}

private int parseContentLength(byte[] headerBytes) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
    ByteArrayInputStream headerIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(headerBytes);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(headerIn);
    return Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH));
}   

public Bitmap readMjpegFrame() throws IOException {
    mark(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH);
    int headerLen = getStartOfSequence(this, SOI_MARKER);
    reset();
    byte[] header = new byte[headerLen];
    readFully(header);
    try {
        mContentLength = parseContentLength(header);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
        mContentLength = getEndOfSeqeunce(this, EOF_MARKER); 
    }
    reset();
    byte[] frameData = new byte[mContentLength];
    skipBytes(headerLen);
    readFully(frameData);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameData));
}
}
```

so what I want to do now is to add two objects so I get two squares for streaming
and I want to add a button if the user click then it displays the information of the streamed path

Here is my xlm file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/r1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <de.mjpegsample.MjpegView
        android:id="@+id/mjpegView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/r2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

        <de.mjpegsample.MjpegView
        android:id="@+id/mjpegView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

   </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

another thing is want to add some functions that will get executed when the user touch the screen of the streaming, but I'm still figuring out how can I do this

Now my question is there another way to place my objects on my layout other than the way I'm using, I mean can I define my objects as 
`MyClass obj1 = new MyClass(this);` this way I can call the functions without a problem

or if there is another way to fix this

here is the error message from logcat

```
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)

11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:137)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5211)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
11-20 11:06:32.732: E/AndroidRuntime(5620):     ... 12 more
```

I tried doing this just to test if it is going to work and same thing happened the application crashed

```
 FrameLayout f1;
 f1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame1);
 TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
 t.setText("Hello world");
 f1.addView(t);
```

but when I tried this it worked

```
 FrameLayout f1 = new FrameLayout(this); 
 TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
 t.setText("Hello world");
 f1.addView(t);
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current method?

Comment: I couldn't find any issue with current method, since there should be no difference if the custom view is inflated from layout or created programmatically... perhaps the function doesn't have `public` access modifier?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare it is not working the application is crashing and I spent two days to know where is the problem coming from and this is what I found the moment I call the function it just shutdown 
when I changed that and called my function before and then at the end I did `setContentView(obj1);` everything worked fine, but that means the obj1 is going to take all page and I need to add other objects

Comment: @AndrewT. it is public that is why as I was saying in the previous comment I can call it if I create an object with the regular java way `MyClass obj1 = new MyClass(this);`

Comment: ok.. the only way one could solve this is when you post the actual code. You are probably getting NPE somewhere.. please postt the `onCreate` method completely and `other objects` that your are talking about..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I added the code to the question

Comment: Where is your `setContentView()` to the specified XML file? Does the above code work? Looks like it will crash because `findViewById` will return null.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare it is there I just missed it when I was copying

Comment: So it is still crashing? Can you post the log? If it is not crashing.. then can you tell the difference between what you see and what you want?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare yes it is still crashing, I added the error message from the logcat

Comment: Somehow I belive the code you posted is not the code you are running. You package name and class name are different from the one in the `error log` What on line `137` of main activity?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41510/discussion-between-amulya-khare-and-lily)