# Android and MJPEG + SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, mjpeg, setcontentview

Good night,

I'm using an IP camera and takes place the display at the bottom of activity, I used the example of this ([Android and MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg?answertab=votes#tab-top)) but I need to put link viewing on a SurfaceView, for example, because I have some buttons just above. 
     I need to replace it "setContentView (mv);" by something that puts on SurfaceView.

Piece of code that would have to be modified:

```
package de.mjpegsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import de.mjpegsample.MjpegView.MjpegInputStream;
import de.mjpegsample.MjpegView.MjpegView;

public class MjpegSample extends Activity {

    private MjpegView mv;
    private static final int MENU_QUIT = 1;

    /* Creates the menu items */
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
    menu.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, "Quit");
    return true;
    }

    /* Handles item selections */
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case MENU_QUIT:
                finish();
                return true;    
            }    
        return false;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        //sample public cam
        String URL = "http://192.168.1.110/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=";

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        mv = new MjpegView(this);

        //MODIFICAR ABAIXO PARA COLOCAR NO SURFACEVIEW.
        setContentView(mv);        

        mv.setSource(MjpegInputStream.read(URL));
        mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);
        mv.showFps(false);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mv.stopPlayback();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/ ... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks, modified language.