# Ip stream viewer app shuts itself, it compile with no errors

Tags: android, stream, ip, ip-camera, mjpeg

My app keeps shutting itself but the code appears to don't have any errors, I think I'm missing something but I'm unable to see.

Here, I took this code as example, [Android and MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg)

while USB debuggin i got:
Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse

Also in **MpegSample** importing **MjpegView** and **MjpegInputStream** seems to be "unused"

**MjpegSample**

```
package com.example.rauls.webviewpfcactivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.example.rauls.webviewpfcactivity.MjpegInputStream;
import com.example.rauls.webviewpfcactivity.MjpegView;
/* android studio says that both import statements are unused
*/

public class MjpegSample extends Activity {

private MjpegView mv;
private static final int MENU_QUIT = 1;

/* Creates the menu items */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, "Quit");
    return true;
}

/* Handles item selections */
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_QUIT:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    //sample public cam
    String URL = "http://192.168.1.64:8081/";

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    mv = new MjpegView(this);
    setContentView(mv);
    mv.setSource(MjpegInputStream.read(URL));
    mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);
    mv.showFps(false);
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mv.stopPlayback();
}
}
```

**MjegView**

```
 package com.example.rauls.webviewpfcactivity;

/**
* Created by RaulS on 19/12/2015.
*/


    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MjpegView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
public final static int POSITION_UPPER_LEFT  = 9;
public final static int POSITION_UPPER_RIGHT = 3;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_LEFT  = 12;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT = 6;

public final static int SIZE_STANDARD   = 1;
public final static int SIZE_BEST_FIT   = 4;
public final static int SIZE_FULLSCREEN = 8;

private MjpegViewThread thread;
private MjpegInputStream mIn = null;
private boolean showFps = false;
private boolean mRun = false;
private boolean surfaceDone = false;
private Paint overlayPaint;
private int overlayTextColor;
private int overlayBackgroundColor;
private int ovlPos;
private int dispWidth;
private int dispHeight;
private int displayMode;

public class MjpegViewThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private int frameCounter = 0;
    private long start;
    private Bitmap ovl;

    public MjpegViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) { mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder; }

    private Rect destRect(int bmw, int bmh) {
        int tempx;
        int tempy;
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD) {
            tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
            tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
            return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
        }
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT) {
            float bmasp = (float) bmw / (float) bmh;
            bmw = dispWidth;
            bmh = (int) (dispWidth / bmasp);
            if (bmh > dispHeight) {
                bmh = dispHeight;
                bmw = (int) (dispHeight * bmasp);
            }
            tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
            tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
            return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
        }
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN) return new Rect(0, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
        return null;
    }

    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
        synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) {
            dispWidth = width;
            dispHeight = height;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap makeFpsOverlay(Paint p, String text) {
        Rect b = new Rect();
        p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), b);
        int bwidth  = b.width()+2;
        int bheight = b.height()+2;
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bwidth, bheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
        p.setColor(overlayBackgroundColor);
        c.drawRect(0, 0, bwidth, bheight, p);
        p.setColor(overlayTextColor);
        c.drawText(text, -b.left+1, (bheight/2)-((p.ascent()+p.descent())/2)+1, p);
        return bm;
    }

    public void run() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
        Bitmap bm;
        int width;
        int height;
        Rect destRect;
        Canvas c = null;
        Paint p = new Paint();
        String fps = "";
        while (mRun) {
            if(surfaceDone) {
                try {
                    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                        try {
                            bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                            destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
                            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                            c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                            if(showFps) {
                                p.setXfermode(mode);
                                if(ovl != null) {
                                    height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom-ovl.getHeight();
                                    width  = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right -ovl.getWidth();
                                    c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                }
                                p.setXfermode(null);
                                frameCounter++;
                                if((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000) {
                                    fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter)+"fps";
                                    frameCounter = 0;
                                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {}
                    }
                } finally { if (c != null) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void init(Context context) {
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    thread = new MjpegViewThread(holder, context);
    setFocusable(true);
    overlayPaint = new Paint();
    overlayPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    overlayPaint.setTextSize(12);
    overlayPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    overlayTextColor = Color.WHITE;
    overlayBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
    ovlPos = MjpegView.POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT;
    displayMode = MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD;
    dispWidth = getWidth();
    dispHeight = getHeight();
}

public void startPlayback() {
    if(mIn != null) {
        mRun = true;
        thread.start();
    }
}

public void stopPlayback() {
    mRun = false;
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public MjpegView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); init(context); }
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h) { thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h); }

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surfaceDone = false;
    stopPlayback();
}

public MjpegView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surfaceDone = true;
}
public void showFps(boolean b) {
    showFps = b;
}
public void setSource(MjpegInputStream source) {
    mIn = source;
    startPlayback();
}
public void setOverlayPaint(Paint p) {
    overlayPaint = p;
}
public void setOverlayTextColor(int c) {
    overlayTextColor = c;
}
public void setOverlayBackgroundColor(int c) {
    overlayBackgroundColor = c;
}
public void setOverlayPosition(int p) {
    ovlPos = p;
}
public void setDisplayMode(int s) {
    displayMode = s;
}
}
```

**MjpegInputStream**

```
package com.example.rauls.webviewpfcactivity;

/**
* Created by RaulS on 19/12/2015.
*/

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
public class MjpegInputStream  extends DataInputStream {


private final byte[] SOI_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD8 };
private final byte[] EOF_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD9 };
private final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
private final static int HEADER_MAX_LENGTH = 100;
private final static int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 40000 + HEADER_MAX_LENGTH;
private int mContentLength = -1;

public static MjpegInputStream read(String url) {
    HttpResponse res;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url)));
        return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return null;
}

public MjpegInputStream(InputStream in) { super(new BufferedInputStream(in, FRAME_MAX_LENGTH)); }

private int getEndOfSeqeunce(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int seqIndex = 0;
    byte c;
    for(int i=0; i < FRAME_MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        c = (byte) in.readUnsignedByte();
        if(c == sequence[seqIndex]) {
            seqIndex++;
            if(seqIndex == sequence.length) return i + 1;
        } else seqIndex = 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

private int getStartOfSequence(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int end = getEndOfSeqeunce(in, sequence);
    return (end < 0) ? (-1) : (end - sequence.length);
}

private int parseContentLength(byte[] headerBytes) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
    ByteArrayInputStream headerIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(headerBytes);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(headerIn);
    return Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH));
}

public Bitmap readMjpegFrame() throws IOException {
    mark(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH);
    int headerLen = getStartOfSequence(this, SOI_MARKER);
    reset();
    byte[] header = new byte[headerLen];
    readFully(header);
    try {
        mContentLength = parseContentLength(header);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        mContentLength = getEndOfSeqeunce(this, EOF_MARKER);
    }
    reset();
    byte[] frameData = new byte[mContentLength];
    skipBytes(headerLen);
    readFully(frameData);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameData));
}
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--WebView

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/webview"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /-->

<!--VideoView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" /-->
<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are there any errors or messages from log files? If yes, please edit your question!

Comment: the only one I got:

Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse