# Read a streaming video from ip camera using cordova , is it possible?

Tags: cordova, video-streaming, cordova-plugins, ip-camera

I'm using cordova to developp an hybrid application and I want to read a streaming video from ip camera, and I wanna know if it is possible with cordova?
I find this tuto:[Android and MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg)
but the problem is that I need a hybrid solution not only for android platform